# How to guarantee that job is finished before starting the next step of IntegrationFlow?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-dsl

I have following flow declaration:

```
return flow -> flow.handle(myHandler)                
                .handle(springBatchJobLauncher)              
                .gateway(acknowledgementFlow);
```

launcher looks like this:

```
@ServiceActivator
public JobExecution launch(JobLaunchRequest request) throws JobExecutionException {
    Job job = request.getJob();
    JobParameters jobParameters = request.getJobParameters();

    return jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
}
```

I need to start `acknowledgementFlow` as soon as job started by `springBatchJobLauncher` is finished. Is it guaranteed according this configuration?

Comment: I think if your job launcher is synchronous, it should work as you expect.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine actually it is but I am afraid that job can be changed a bit later and everything will be broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look into the `JobLauncher.run()` JavaDocs!

```
 * Start a job execution for the given {@link Job} and {@link JobParameters}
 * . If a {@link JobExecution} was able to be created successfully, it will
 * always be returned by this method, regardless of whether or not the
 * execution was successful. If there is a past {@link JobExecution} which
 * has paused, the same {@link JobExecution} is returned instead of a new
 * one created. A exception will only be thrown if there is a failure to
 * start the job. If the job encounters some error while processing, the
 * JobExecution will be returned, and the status will need to be inspected.
```

So, if job has started successfully, you'll get a `JobExecution` object, but this indeed doesn't matter that your job has finished or not. For that goal I believe we need to have something like `JobExecutionListener` hook.

See more info in the Spring Batch Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#providing-feedback-with-informational-messages

There is a sample for the `step`:

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "notificationExecutionsListener", defaultRequestChannel = "stepExecutionsChannel")
public interface NotificationExecutionListener extends StepExecutionListener {}
```

But the same approach can be applied for the `JobExecutionListener`.

So, you need to devid your flow two several and have your `.gateway(acknowledgementFlow)` called only from the `afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)` is executed from your job.

Comment: What do you mean when you type **you need to devid your flow two several and have your** ?

Comment: I suppose that I have to invoke **acknowledgementFlow** inside **afterJob**?

Comment: Your first flow must finish with job launcher. The second flow may start from the channel initiated by the gateway on the listener interface